# Why does the plumbing for my whole house filter produce a buzzing/humming sound?

Tags: plumbing

Yesterday, We installed the AquaSana Whole house water filter system by a licensed plumber. After install, We are hearing buzzing/humming sound near the main water line pipes. (Red arrow pointing to where the sound appears.)

[image: buzzing sound]

Comment: Hard to tell from the fuzzy photo, but that looks like a valve with a test port on it. Does the sound change if you close the valve partway?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. U mean closing the red knob partway?

Comment: Since this is a brand new install, you may want to call the company and get them to come check their work. They shouldn't leave things "not right" and if they care about their reputation, they'll be right back out.

Comment: It looks like everything is properly anchored  below the red handle (that is a ball valve 90 degrees shuts off the flow) there is something else is this a pressure regulator?  Commonly called a PRV these are known for noisy operation at very low flow and at full flow.

Answer (score 0):

If your asking what might be causing the sound the first thing to come to mind is a solenoid controlled valve ,but I don't see any in the photo. It may be that it's further along your plumbing system and out of frame. This is common with pipes as the easily transmit sound and vibrations.

It also may be the water traveling through the pipes which does sometimes sound like a hum. This can be amplified by the pipe itself if it is loose and not secured snugly. Air trapped in the line will also cause noticeable odd sounds, but it will eventually get released when a tap is opened.

Sudden opening of valves can cause noises if the water pressure is high enough.

Plastic pipes are also known for not being able to dampen sounds like heavier (metal) pipes do.

Does the U.V. light make any sounds when working? The metal canister on the right edge of the photo.